# True Type font outline overlap detection, and merging C#

Tags: fonts, overlap, truetype

I have an app that displays true type fonts.  I need to combine two characters some times (e.g. Hindi), that may overlap.    I need an algorithm to detect when two font outlines overlap, and merge the two outlines into one.

Answer (score 0):

If the font is OpenType, then it may already have an outline representing these "overlapping" outlines. In font terminology this is called a ligature; a classic example is the string "ffi".see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature.

The tricky bit is detecting the correct sequence of character codes and replacing it with the appropriate glyph outline. I am not sure if C# has an API to do this but the Pango libray (http://www.pango.org/) should be able to handle this.